# I got a binomial question and when trying to solve for p and q I reached $x^8$. Am I wrong?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

- $\left(px-\frac qx\right)^8             $
- fifth term is $5670   $
- $p-q=2  $
- $p$ and $q$ are positive

using this info i got:
$$x^{8}+560x^{7}+1680x^{6}+2240x^{5}+1120x^{4}-5670=0   $$
i am unable to solve this. help. thanks

Comment: btw i subbed in p=2+q into 70(2p^{4}q^{4}) 
from there i got this weird equation

Comment: Welcome to MSE, @CoderHere ! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: what exactly is the "fifth term"? is this sorted in ascending or descending powers of $x$?

Comment: not sorted by x since a and b of binomial expression contains x. so straight from expansion

Comment: from the answer key i got q=1 and p=3, using desmos i put in this                                            x^{8}+560x^{7}+1680x^{6}+2240x^{5}+1120x^{4}-5670=0
and also got q=1, but how tho? how solve equation with power 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "fifth term" you mean the fifth in order of descending degree of $x$, then clearly since there are $8 + 1 = 9$ terms in the expansion, the fifth term is the constant term.  Hence $$\binom{8}{4} p^4 q^4 = 5670,$$ or $pq = 3$.  Then since $p = q + 2$, it follows that $$q(q+2) = 3$$ or $$q \in \{-3, 1\}.$$  Since $q > 0$ we conclude $q = 1$ and $p = 3$, hence $$(px - q/x)^8 = (3x - 1/x)^8.$$  Consequently if we require the roots for this equation, then $3x - 1/x = 0$, or $x = \pm 1/\sqrt{3}$.  There are no other roots; each one has multiplicity $4$.